# Would it create issues if Number were to be implemented as an interface? Are there benefits?

Tags: java, java-8

On a recent question I came accross the use of the `Number` abstract class.

Now since Java 8 is here, there are default methods, so `Number` *could be* an interface and written as:

```
public interface Number {
    public int intValue();

    public long longValue();

    public float floatValue();

    public double doubleValue();

    default public byte byteValue() {
        return (byte)intValue();
    }

    default public short shortValue() {
        return (short)intValue();
    }
}
```

Would old code using the `Number` abstract class still compile if this were the case? Are there any actual benefits in making `Number` an interface rather than an abstract class?

Comment: "Would old code using the Number abstract class still compile" <-- well no, since one is an abstract class and another an interface (extends vs implements). Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @fge You did understand it correctly, I had overlooked that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of changes would certainly break the API immediately, and cause havoc into the world of Java programming. You just can't change a class (that too, the one which existed since the time Java is there), into an interface, because both have different meanings. And both are used in different ways.

For example, as soon as you make `Number` an interface, the immediate subclasses, say, `Integer` would break, as a class cannot `extend` from an interface, but has to implement it. But `Integer` class extends from `Number`.

You might argue that while changing `Number`, Java API designer could also change necessary subclasses in Java API accordingly. But they can't ignore the fact that, someone else might have their classes that extend from `Number`.

One more thing regarding the fact from which this question arose - an `interface` with default methods is not the same as an `abstract` class. This has been [discussed quite a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22591499/1679863) [on SO itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18198517/1679863), one of which is answered by you only.